# How can I make preg_replace work in all PHP environments?

Tags: php, encoding, preg-replace

My function using preg_replace is working perfectly on a dev server, but not at all on the production server.  The problem might have something to do with encoding. Is there a way to make this expression so that it works regardless of the encoding?

The $config looks like this:

```
class JConfig {
    public $mighty = array("0" => array("0" => "/`?\\#__mightysites[` \\n]+/u"), "1" => array("0" => "`hhd_mightysites` "));
    public $mighty_enable = '0';
    public $mighty_language = '';
    public $mighty_template = '9';
    public $mighty_home = '';
    public $mighty_langoverride = '0';......
```

I put the variables associated with the lines I would like to strip in an array called strips like

```
$strips = array(
    'mighty',
    'mighty_enable',
    'mighty_sync',
    'mighty_language',
    'mighty_template',.....
```

Then use a loop to strip out the lines:

```
foreach ($strips as $var) {
    if (JString::strpos($config, 'public $' . $var . ' =') !== false) {
        $config = preg_replace('/\tpublic \$' . $var . ' \= ([^\;]*)\;\n/u', '', $config);
        $tempvar .= $var . ", ";
    }
}
```

Again, it works perfectly on our dev server.  It does not do anything to any lines on the production server. I also know that it passes the strpos like to get to the line with preg_replace.  Can I make preg_replace environment proof?

I appreciate the help, since it is happening only on a production server it is very difficult to test!

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it cause errors?

Comment: Is the source file the same? Or could the one on the server have `\r` instead of the `\n`?

Comment: You don't need to escape everything in your regex. Equals and semicolons are not special, and you've got an unneeded group in there as well. This should be sufficient: `'/\tpublic \$' . $var . ' = [^;]+;\n/u'` or, since you don't care about the content `'/^\s*public \$' . $var . ' =.*$/'` should be fine.

Comment: no, just returns the line/file exactly as it was prior to the preg_replace.  My suspicion is it is not matching.  I put two files from the two different servers freshly copied from my pc into winmerge, and it was 100% red.  So I believe the means the server is encoding them differently?  And maybe that is why it is not matching?

Comment: the changes worked on the dev server, do you think that will solve the problem on the production server?

Comment: I don't see any sample input data for `$config` in your question.  How can we reproduce the issue?  When you give us some realistic input data and then tell us your exact expected result, we can offer pattern refinements for you that will not only be reliable, but will improve performance, brevity, and readability.  Posting a "complete" question also helps to prevent downvotes on your post.

Comment: You code can be executed without the `strpos()` call.  After you offer all of the required question details, I'll be able to offer my insights as an answer.  (I'm always eager to help a Joomlite)

Comment: $config is the top data.  I don't believe the rest of the file matters. The problem is I can't reproduce it unless it on the production server.  It works perfectly on the dev server.  So I was hoping someone would know how preg_replace could be affected by the OS or encoding?  I don't understand why.  The files are the exact same on the PC. I believe it has something to do with the encoding because as I said when I download them, and load them into winmerge, it shows all red which typically means they are encoded differently.

Comment: Oh, `$config` is the whole file's text that includes a class.  My suspicion is that it is the difference between `\r\n` and `\n`.  So `\R` should do the trick.  I'll write something up.  p.s. I didn't get an alert from you because you didn't use @mickmackusa .  I just happened to check in again.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry @mickmackusa! #learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest bet would be to not "trust" any of the literal spaces/tabs that you expect to match.

Instead of using `\t` and , I'll recommend `\s+` where you expect a tab and `\s` where you expect a space.

Furthermore, to cover cases where the operating system may use `\r\n` or `\n` at the end of each line, you can use `\R` to match both variations.

I'm going to include a start of line character check via `^` at the beginning of the pattern and `m` as a pattern modifier.  This ensures that we match and only match where you expect a `\t` at the start of the line.

Finally, `preg_replace()` has an optional 5th parameter that counts how many replacements were made.  If `$found` is a non-zero value, then store the current `$var` value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jkI5P))

```
$config = <<<'CONFIG'
class JConfig {
    public $mighty = array("0" => array("0" => "/`?\\#__mightysites[` \\n]+/u"), "1" => array("0" => "`hhd_mightysites` "));
    public $mighty_enable = '0';
    public $mighty_language = '';
    public $mighty_template = '9';
    public $mighty_home = '';
    public $mighty_langoverride = '0';......
CONFIG;

$strips = [
    'mighty',
    'mighty_enable',
    'mighty_sync',
    'mighty_language',
    'mighty_template'
];

$tempvar = '';
foreach ($strips as $var) {
    $config = preg_replace('~^\s+public\s\$' . $var . '\s=\s[^;]*;\R~um', '', $config, -1, $found);
    if ($found) {
        $tempvar .= $var . ", ";
    }
}
echo "\$tempvar = $tempvar\n\n";
echo $config;
```

Output:

```
$tempvar = mighty, mighty_enable, mighty_language, mighty_template, 

class JConfig {
    public $mighty_home = '';
    public $mighty_langoverride = '0';......
```

p.s. One final suggested refinement...  If you don't *actually* need the `$tempvar` variable for your project (meaning you are only using this during debugging) then you can avoid the loop entirely, and just `implode('|', $strips)`, wrap that generated string in `(` and `)`, save as `$var`, and call `preg_replace()` just one time.  This will be more efficient and your sample `$strips` data does not need to be prepared with `preg_quote()` because there are you "special characters" to escape.

Comment: Thanks! I will test it out in 12 hours.

Comment: worked perfectly.  Thanks for implementing $found - very helpful!